# Partition is not getting formatted.

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning, clean-install

Recently my Western Digital 250Gb Hard Drive failed so I get a new same WD 250 gb in replacement. Now I am trying to install windows 7 ultimate with SP1 so whenever I make a primary partition of 50 Gb to install Os It makes the reserved partition of 350Mb finely but when I try to format the drive to install os it stops with an error "We couldn't format this partition Error 80070057" (sometimes 80070003). I thought the replaced Hard drive has some issue so I changed it and the other one gives me the same response. I even changed OS (other copy of W7) but still stuck at formatting partition. PLEASE HELP!!!

Comment: You should allow the Windows installer make the partitions.

Comment: Of course it's the windows installer that is formatting the partition and giving error.

Comment: Install Windows on a disk with zero partitions and it will work.  The way you have worded your question tells me your creating the partitions yourself

Comment: Is the partitioning tool running on a different drive than the one you are trying to format, right?

Answer (score 0):

What about using diskpart, then do a CLEAN on the drive to delete any existing partitions and set it to "uninitialized"? This has worked for me in the past when I've had the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You may try partitioning the drive from a partitioning tool installed on an external support (from its ISO file) and launched in live mode (i.e. running on the RAM instead than in C:\ or any other drive installed on your pc; this is very comfortable if you haven't a different drive installed on your pc where to run the partitioning tool from or if you want avoiding the possibility to run into incompatibility issues between the partitioning tool and some other softwares or processes running in your system); for instance, you may create a live-CD or a live USB stick by using several tools like YUMI, Unebootin or Rufus for this purpose.

Me I found very comfortable partitioning my C:\ drive with GParted live launched from a USB-stick (formatted and created with [YUMI](http://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/yumi-portable)).

Tou can download the ISO from here->

[GPArted live for USB (ISO)](http://gparted.org/liveusb.php)

[GPArted ISOs for different live solutions (HD, PXE, USB)](http://gparted.org/livecd.php)

Answer (score 0):

It may occur because you boot to the disk from BIOS. Let the disk invoke the BIOS to use the disk as a boot device. I request you to try the following possible solutions:

- Reset your BIOS.
- Hard reset your BIOS by removing the CMOS Battery and inserting it again.
- Set hard disk SATA configuration to Compatibility/IDE Mode if it is set to AHCI mode.
- When you insert boot media, you'll get a message "Press any key to boot from CD/DVD.....", do not press any key and it will prompt this message again. Then press a key.

This may solve the issue. If not, your motherboard may have some problem. Get it checked by an expert.